# Google Map Markers With Url

Tags: javascript, google-maps, marker

I really cant understand javascript, i know it should be a very easy question but i stucked..
I have a google map with multiple markers and i added every marker and work perfect but i wanted to give them links. My locations array is like;

```
['http://website.com',36.598900,35.202094,'1']
```

i use [1] and [2] as lat long but i wanted to use [0] as link. My loop works perfect but every marker's link going to last item's link

Here is my loop

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon: image,
    url: locations[i][0],
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    window.location.href = marker.url;
  });

}
```

Where did i make the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1/ You need to add `var` before `marker = new google.maps.Marker({` ,

Because , you use now `marker` as Global variable which is overridden for each  iteration.

2/ Anyway, best practices are to save all markers as object attributes . Let's call this Object: `mk` , then your markers will be `mk.marker0`,`mk.marker1`,...so on.

```
var mk={}; // this is nameSpace to save all markers
locations.map((loc,i)=>{
    mk['marker'+i] = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(loc[1], loc[2]),
      map: map,
      icon: image,
      url: loc[0],
    });
    return mk['marker'+i];
}).forEach((marker)=>{
              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                  window.location.href = marker.url;
             });    

 })
```

Comment: you are right i added var before marker but nothing changed. Still all link to the last items url value

Comment: @ÇağdaşTakış : I update the answer , it will work now.. be sure

Comment: hhhh. not at all , ,last year, i implemented many algo using ESRI, Google Maps & Oracle Spacial ,, this is the best way i found to deal with this kind of issues